# Setting up OpenGL projects in VS2010 with freeglut/glew

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, glew, freeglut

I am following the following tutorial my instructor used in class for a graphics class that started last week.

http://cse.spsu.edu/jchastin/courses/cs4363/labs/ProjectSetup/Project_Setup.html

I am trying to set this up under Win8 using VS2010 pro.

I copied freeglut.dll and glew32.dll to C:\windows\sysWOW64

I get to step 5 to include the include directories - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li5FV.png

I get to step 7 to include the dependencies - https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkjrB.png

And finally to step 8 for the library directories - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kll8u.png

I try to compile and I get what seem to be linkage errors according to a quick google search - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aDGT.png

Google says its a linkage error but everything seems to be linked properly on my end. Is there something I am missing since this is under Windows 8?

Thanks for looking.

Edit: Playing around with the linker directories. I am linking them to:

\freeglut-2.8.1\lib\x86

\glew-1.10.0\lib\Release\Win32

takes the error count down to 23 errors. :)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4vqo.png

Edit2: freeglut.h is located at \freeglut-2.8.1\include\GL and glew.h is located at \glew-1.10.0\include\GL and both of those are pointing right include directories under C/C++/General's tab.

Comment: You mention `glew32.dll` and `freeglut.dll` but are statically linking against the `lib`s.  Are you sure the `lib`s reside where you expect them to?

Comment: are you using modern openGL or the fixed function pipeline?

Comment: I am not sure. This is a intro to graphics programming class and I was using what was suggested in the tutorial above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the full path of glew's libs is **\glew-1.10.0\lib\Release\Win32**(I suppose you use 32bit windows), make sure you path include the lib files correctly. if you didn't modify the directory structure, /glew-1.10.0/lib won't find the libs you want.

Do the same thing for glut libs, I see you got glut link errors as well.

VC++ Directory settings in Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: It's x64 and at first I did have it set to: 
\glew-1.10.0\lib\Release\x64 
\glew-1.10.0\include\GL 
\freeglut-2.8.1\lib\x64 
\freeglut-2.8.1\include\GL 

I was playing with the directories and was still getting linker errors so I went back to the tutorial defaults.

I am not sure whats up exactly.

Comment: @Arcath so you're building x64? because I see your project set to `WIN32`

Comment: I have tried the x86 and x64 directories to link to just trying to figure out if that was a problem. Yeah, It's set to Win32 but setting to the win32/x86 directories didn't fix anything. Sorry if I wasnt clear.

Comment: @Arcath, can you try to set it on the VC++ Directories tab? see the pictures in my answer.

Comment: Yes, this solved the linker errors. But it's throwing an application error when running now. http://i.imgur.com/VOdofyQ.png Time to see if I can figure this out in google. Thanks for the help tonight. :)